# In cmd can I dir /s but only to n sub directories?

Tags: windows, cmd, dir

In the Windows command shell, `cmd`, is there a way to `C:> dir /s` but only to n sub directories?

Seems to me that I have made this work in the past, though I may have corrupted that sector in my brain with certain cell damaging liquids... :P

I guess I could redirect the output into a log and then skim it with findstr or qgerp but it seems like there should be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cleaner way"?  With DOS commands like "dir"?  You've got a dry sense of humor, there ;)

You can do a "dos /?" to query available options.  "limit recursion to 'n' directores with /s" is definitely not one of them.

If you want to do that, you'd need to write your own program ... or redirect to a text file and parse the file.